# What am I doing wrong? Php,mysql insert or query does not work

Tags: php, mysql

I am having an issues with my registration script. Whether I enter data and send it to the server it just displays an "something went wrong" costum message even if the table is empty.

Code:

```
<?php

$mysql_host = "localhost";
$mysql_database = "accountsmessengertesttable";
$mysql_user = "root";
$mysql_password = "";

$username = $_GET['username'];
$password = $_GET['password'];
$phone_number = $_GET['phone_num'];

$connect = mysqli_connect($mysql_host,  $mysql_user, $mysql_password, $mysql_database);

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

    $check_for_user = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT username FROM accounts WHERE username = MD5('$username')"); 
    $check_for_number = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT phone_number FROM accounts WHERE phone_number = MD5('$phone_number')");


    if(mysqli_num_rows($check_for_user) == 0 && mysqli_num_rows($check_for_number) == 0) {
        $register = mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO accounts (username, password, phone_number) VALUES (MD5('$username'), MD5('$password'), MD5('$phone_number')"); 
    if($register) {
    echo  "registered";
    }
    else { echo "something went wrong"; 
    }
    }

     else if(!mysqli_num_rows($check_for_user) == 0) {
                echo "user_exists";
     } else if(!mysqli_num_rows($check_for_number) == 0) {

     echo "number_exists";

     }




mysqli_close($connect);

?>
```

Comment: Why are you encrypting the username and phonenumber in the database?

Comment: The instructions in the "if" are returning true or false? Maybe the script doesn't enter the query because of that.

And I don't understand why you are hashing all the info, it just makes sense that you use the MD% or something like that to the password. How will you present or know the real username when you are doing that?

Comment: change `echo "something went wrong";` => `echo mysqli_error($connect);` and check the error

Comment: if(!mysqli_query('YourQuery')){ echo mysqli_error(); }

Comment: PHPhil 
Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\reg_auth.php on line 23

Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\reg_auth.php on line 23
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '\'(MD5('"borut"')\', \'MD5('"pocakaj"')\', \'MD5('"041341323"')\'' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

To insert strings in database you must add `''` Try this

```
<?php

$mysql_host = "localhost";
$mysql_database = "accountsmessengertesttable";
$mysql_user = "root";
$mysql_password = "";

$username = $_GET['username'];
$password = $_GET['password'];
$phone_number = $_GET['phone_num'];

$connect = mysqli_connect($mysql_host,  $mysql_user, $mysql_password, $mysql_database);

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

    $check_for_user = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT username FROM accounts WHERE username = \'MD5('$username')\'"); 
    $check_for_number = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT phone_number FROM accounts WHERE phone_number = \'MD5('$phone_number')\'");


    if(mysqli_num_rows($check_for_user) == 0 && mysqli_num_rows($check_for_number) == 0) {
        $register = mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO accounts (username, password, phone_number) VALUES \'(MD5('$username')\', \'MD5('$password')\', \'MD5('$phone_number')\'"); 
    if($register) {
    echo  "registered";
    }
    else { echo "something went wrong"; 
    }
    }

     else if(!mysqli_num_rows($check_for_user) == 0) {
                echo "user_exists";
     } else if(!mysqli_num_rows($check_for_number) == 0) {

     echo "number_exists";

     }




mysqli_close($connect);

?>
```

Comment: I got this error: 
Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\reg_auth.php on line 23

Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\reg_auth.php on line 23
something went wrong

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$mysql_host = "localhost";
$mysql_database = "accountsmessengertesttable";
$mysql_user = "root";
$mysql_password = "";

$username = $_GET['username'];
$password = $_GET['password'];
$phone_number = $_GET['phone_num'];

$connect = mysqli_connect($mysql_host,  $mysql_user, $mysql_password, $mysql_database);

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

    $check_for_user = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT username FROM accounts WHERE username = '".MD5($username)."'"); 
    $check_for_number = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT phone_number FROM accounts WHERE phone_number = '".MD5($phone_number)."'");


    if(mysqli_num_rows($check_for_user) == 0 && mysqli_num_rows($check_for_number) == 0) {
        $register = mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO accounts (username, password, phone_number) VALUES ('".MD5($username)."', '".MD5($password)."','". MD5($phone_number)."'"); 
    if($register) {
    echo  "registered";
    }
    else { echo "something went wrong"; 
    }
    }

     else if(!mysqli_num_rows($check_for_user) == 0) {
                echo "user_exists";
     } else if(!mysqli_num_rows($check_for_number) == 0) {

     echo "number_exists";

     }




mysqli_close($connect);

?>
```